# How to fix "Multiple-stop OLE DB operation..." errors when using ADO Command to run stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run a SQL Server stored procedure that returns records using an ADO Command object. I'm able to connect to the database (my connection is used elsewhere in my code and, when tested in the following function, the state property returns 1 -- connected) but get the following error at the point where the command is executed.

> Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)':
>   Multiple-stop OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLD DB status value, if available. No work was done.

From what I've read online, it may be something to do with the parameter, but I can't see anything wrong with it (I've added a watch and inspected each item in the params collection in debug mode).

Here's the function that is intended to return the stored procedure results in an ADODB Recordset:

```
Public Function GetRecordset(CmdType As String, CmdText As String, Optional InputParams As Collection) As ADODB.Recordset

        Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

        Select Case CmdType
            Case "proc"
                If cmd Is Nothing Then

                    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

                    With cmd
                        Set .ActiveConnection = GetConnection

                        For Each prm In InputParams
                            .Parameters.Append prm
                        Next prm

                        Select Case CmdType
                            Case "proc": .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                            Case "sql": .CommandType = adCmdText
                        End Select

                        .CommandText = CmdText
                        Set rs = .Execute
                    End With

                    Set GetRecordset = rs

                End If

            Case "sql"

        End Select
End Function
```

As above, the error occurs on the line:

```
Set rs = .Execute
```

The expected input parameter in the stored procedure is of type numeric(6,0).  The parameter passed to the function is as follows:

```
prm.Direction = adParamInput
prm.Name = "@ISOWk"
prm.NumericScale = 6
prm.Precision = 0
prm.Type = adNumeric
prm.Value = 201613
```

I'm able to execute the stored procedure directly in SSMS so I am confident that it is not the issue here.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Comment: you need to use rs.open, execute executes nonquery sql what is cmdText

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Nathan_Sav.  It is my understanding that the `command.execute` method returns a recordset, which I should be able to assign to the recordset (I've done this successfully in the past).  Please could you give an example of what you mean?  Thanks

Comment: I would use execute for sql of "insert into table(field1) values 'xyz'" and for sql of "Select * from table" or when expecting a return I'd use rs.open(SQL,CONNECTION,TYPE) on reading it looks like cmd.execute should return, i'll keep reading.  What are you passing in as cmdText?  Also, on a side note, there is no need for the inner select case.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the extra `select case`, Nathan_Sav.  I plan to use the function for returning recordsets from SQL queries and SQL stored procedures, so I'm trying to write a single function to deal with both.  Currently, my `cmdText` function parameter/argument will contain either the name of a stored procedure or an SQL query as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `.Precision` and `.Scale` backwards:

```
prm.NumericScale = 6
prm.Precision = 0
```

A value with a precision of 0 can store 0 digits.  If the data-type is `NUMERIC(6, 0)` the parameter should be:

```
prm.NumericScale = 0
prm.Precision = 6
```

Precision is the number on the left.

Comment: Thank you, Comintern!  It's often the simplest of things (this has taken up around 2 hours of my time this afternoon)!